# php won't work in head of the html

Tags: php, html

I have a header.php and a home.php.

I am trying to pass in title and description from my home.php to header.php.
Issue is in my header.php, in the   dom : my php variable are not been seen or php won't work in the head of my html only while it works fine in the body.

Any Suggestions?

here are my files: 
Header.php:

```
<?php session_start(); 
    header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

    function sendPageInfo($title, $desc){
    if($title)
        $pageTitle= $title;
    if($desc)
        $description = $desc; 

    echo $pageTitle;
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title><?php echo $pageTitle; ?></title> //the $pageTitle won't show up!!!
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name ="description" content=" <?php echo $description; ?> "> //$description won't show
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/menu.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/pages.css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
    <link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>
<section class="bodyWrap"> 
<?php echo $pageTitle; ?> //// PAGE TITLE DOES SHOW UP!!!!!!!!!!!
    <section class="headerNav">
        <div class="logo">

        </div>
        <nav class="tpMenu shdw">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="events" href="events.php">Events</a></li>
                <li><a class="press" href="pressNotes.php">Press</a></li>
                <li><a class="media" href="eventsalbum.php">Media</a></li>
                <li><a class="about" href="about.php">Our Vision</a></li>
                <li><a class="contact" href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
<!--This is where you add memeber.php if the user is signed in-->
                 <?php
                  if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))
                  {
                  echo "<li><a href=\"MemberLogin.php\"> Login</a></li>";
                  }
                  ?>
                 <?php
                  if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
                  {
                    echo "Welcome! &nbsp;";
                    echo $_SESSION['username'];
                    echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                    echo "<li><a href=\"logout.php\">Log out</a></li>";
                  }
                  ?>
                  </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
    </section>
```

home.php:

```
<?php include_once("includes/header.php");
    sendPageInfo('Troy Telugu Association Home', 'A Nonprofit organization fouced on South Indian culture in Troy, Michigan'); 
?>

<?php include_once("addHomeContentAlbum.php");?>

<?php include_once("includes/footer.php");?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP variables do not work the way you are using them.

When you include your header, your html will be immediately created and either echoed or buffered depending on if you are using buffers.

At this time, your pageTitle is undefined, so nothing will be echoed.

Your function will never be able to change the page title since it will already have been echoed by the time it is called (PHP variables do not work how you would like here though some templating enginges can do what you are trying to do with references).

Try directly setting the page title before including your header rather than using your function.

Comment: But i don't understand, why it is getting read in the body of the section?? head and body are on the same php doc.

Answer (score 3):

The function `sendPageInfo` is never called and does not modify any global variables. It only creates new function local variables.

Comment: sendPageInfo is called and your answer doesn't address the real issue

Comment: The real issue is that `$pageTitle` and `$description` are global variables that never get set, even if you had called the function before accessing them.

Comment: Your answer is still incorrect. The function is called. It also doesn't matter if it uses locals or globals because PHP doesn't work the way he is trying to use it (he is expecting references or late bindings which aren't being used here). Not to mention because the function is defined in header.php which immediately echos, means the function could never be called before header.php is included.

Comment: The function is definitely begin called, because I get the variables in my body. I am still confused why is that that it only appears in the body but not the head of my html?

Comment: It appears in the body because you echo in your function. It should appear exactly after the header since that is where you call your function.

Answer (score 2):

You don't call `sendPageInfo()` until after `include_once("includes/header.php")`. So, `$pageTitle` is undefined while the header is being included.

The `$pageTitle` that *does* show up is the one that you echo in `sendPageInfo()`.

Comment: (Also, as knittl points out, you need to declare `global $pageTitle` inside `sendPageInfo()` if you want it to modify the global variable.)

Comment: so where should I put my function then?  I can't put it before i call include_one("includes/header.php");

Comment: I would just put `$pageTitle = 'Troy Telugu Association Home'` in `home.php` prior to `include_once("includes/header.php")`.

Answer (score 0):

Others answered why it doesn't work (*those variables don't exist outside the function*).  Instead of monkeying around with globals, just do this in home.php:

```
<?php
$pageTitle   = 'Troy Telugu Association Home';
$description = 'A Nonprofit organization fouced on South Indian culture in Troy, Michigan';
include_once("includes/header.php");
```

Comment: I want it to be very modular, I can't do this in the home.php. I have many other pages and sites i need to pass different titles and descriptions. I also need to check if the titles aren't getting passed, assign a default title.

Comment: That's not modular.  You are already doing this `sendPageInfo('Troy Telugu Association Home', 'A Nonprofit organization fouced on South Indian culture in Troy, Michigan');' in home.php, what's the diff?

Comment: then is it best practice to check in my header.php if the titles exist or to assign a default value?

Answer (score 0):

Look at incl.php:

```
<?php
function write_head($title, $descr){
   echo "<head>\n";
   echo "   <title>$title</title>\n";
   echo "   <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\">\n";
   echo "   <meta name =\"description\" content=\"$descr\">\n";
   echo "</head>\n";
}//write_head
?>
```

and index.php:

```
<html>
<?php
   include_once("incl.php");
   write_head('Troy Telugu Association Home', 'A Nonprofit organization fouced on South Indian culture in Troy, Michigan');
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<body>
<h1>Stackoverflow is cool</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

It is a simplified version of what you are trying to and it works.
You are confused by the result of the line "//// PAGE TITLE DOES SHOW UP!!!!!!!!!!!".
But I think you are mistaken.
The title showing up is from line:
   "    echo $pageTitle;"
within
   "function sendPageInfo($title, $desc){"

As mentioned by the other posters, $pageTitle is only valid within "sendPageInfo". You are using it outside its scope. It's not globally visible.